# We got error in style.xml file When we import existing project to eclipse

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

We tried to add project to eclipse. Now we got Error this

`error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.`

And then we googled.We followed this

```
Right click android-support-v7-mediarouter project, select Properties
Select Android
In the Library section at the bottom, click Add....
Select android-support-v7-appcompat in the dialog.
Click Apply.
Click OK.
Do a clean build on the android-support-v7-mediarouter project.
```

But We have no luck.So any one guide me how to solve my problem.

Comment: Did you import appcomp lib to your project?

Comment: @Ranjith No, thank for reply We new to eclipse so Please guide me how to add appcomp lib to my project

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have downloaded the **Android Support Library** using the SDK Manager.

Create a `libs/` directory in the root of your application project.
Copy the JAR file from your Android SDK installation directory (e.g., `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`) into your application's project `libs/` directory.

Right click the JAR file and select `Build Path > Add to Build Path`.

For more information:

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: we tried as you said .In .xml error solved But we got new error 
D:\Softwares\Android\Practice\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.      if you any thing about this, Please inform to me

Comment: Compile your project with API 21, that will fix that error.